# how i can change file permission in php or magento?

Tags: php, .net, magento

I have one application which is running on two platform i.e .net and php. The product is created from .net(on windows) server and saved on php(on linux) server. I want to copy that file programmatically but when i am accessing that file it fails.. Permission denied. 
we gave 777 permission from both side while creating and accessing. Anyone know solution?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/chmod

```
Attempts to change the mode of the specified file to that given in mode.
```

Comment: I gave 777 but it failed to access. And while creating the file he also gave 777 permission to that file.

Comment: maybe need set permission on folder, where this file ? Or you get error with set permission on file?

Answer (score 0):

try this- take a backup of your .htaccess file and write this in your .htaccess-

```
# enable directory browsing
Options All +Indexes    
order deny,allow
allow from all
```